# Direct asp.net site to new database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

What is the easiest way to redirect my asp.net website (entity framework) to a new database.  The database is identical, its just on a new server..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your connection string in web.config to the new server, or where ever you may store it.

Comment: Ah yes, completely forgot about web.config

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Connection String that you are using, or when you create your model instance use this ctor overload:

```
public EntitiesContext()
            :base("newConnectionString")
        {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the connection in your web.config or app.config file.

[How to: Define the Connection String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896291.aspx)